# Color loss in matplotlib using savefig

Tags: python, matplotlib

Recently I need to save vector field configuration, and I made a color map myself:

```
    cdict = {'red':   ((0.0,  1.0, 1.0),
                   (1.0/3.0,  0.0, 0.0),
                   (2.0/3.0,  0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0,  1.0, 1.0)),

         'green': ((0.0,  0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0/3.0,  1.0, 1.0),
                   (2.0/3.0,  0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0,  0.0, 0.0)),

         'blue':  ((0.0,  0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0/3.0,  0.0, 0.0),
                   (2.0/3.0,  1.0, 1.0),
               (1.0,  0.0, 0.0))}
```

I made the plot, it was color just as I think, the color changes smoothly from red to yellow, green, cyan, blue, magenta and back to red. But it only looks good when I use `show()`. Blue parts turn magenta and cyan and yellow are indistinguishable when I use `savefig()`, or I save directly from the plotting GUI.

Has anyone met this kind of problem before? Thanks.

Forgot to mention, I use `pcolor()` for coloring the plot, if it could be relevant.

Comment: It's OK to save in pdf form, but it will be really a pain to look at hundreds of pdf files. I'm now trying other formats.

Comment: also in ps, eps, and svg. svg is acceptable, the problem is somehow solved.

Comment: Why not using png? These are also compressed in lossless mode and they are nice to work with, if a fixed-pixel format is ok. (you did not tell us what formats you tested; i assume there is some loss due to usage of lossy formats like jpg).

Comment: I used png and then tried jpeg. They both lost some color. It shouldn't be the problem of saving format but of the saving method of matplotlib. It would be nicer if I can post the figures in the question.

Comment: I tried converting the svg files into png files using __imagemagick__ and saw the loss of color again. So it should has nothing to do with `matplotlib` or python, it's a problem of compressed images.